# How to get the equations from Mathpix API string response

Tags: java, android, string

when i click photo from camera of mathematics 3 equations solving problem.

Mathpix API Give response like this :

**"\left. \beginarray  l   2 x + 3 y + 3 z = 8  \  3 x + y + 2 z = 10  \  8 x + 9 x + 10 z = 12  \endarray \right."**

I want to get three equations from this string (Response Of API) using pattern matching or whatever is the best solution.To Calculate it from Edittext.

Comment: So what would the desired output be for the given sample input?

Comment: 1) 2x+3y+3z=8 2)3x+y+_2z=10 3)8x+9x+10z=12 something like this .. all three equations separated. @Yunnosch

Comment: Why did you delete what seems to be division operators?

Comment: What are the rules? "Everything after '\beginarray" and before '\endarray', split where the '/' are and counted up." ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: use `String.split` by `\`, removing `"\left. \beginarray l` and `\endarray \right."` beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is 100% accurate for the syntax, I offer this solution:

```
\\\\left\\.\\s+\\\\beginarray\\s+l\\s+([\\d\\s\\+=\\-*\\/%^x-z]+)\\s+\\\\\\s+([\\d\\s\\+=\\-*\\/%^x-z]+)\\s+\\\\\\s+([\\d\\s\\+=\\-*\\/%^x-z]+)\\s+\\\\endarray\\s+\\\\right\\.
```

Using this regex pattern, you'd receive the following strings

```
Group1 == "2 x + 3 y + 3 z = 8"
Group2 == "3 x + y + 2 z = 10"
Group3 == "8 x + 9 x + 10 z = 12"
```

Note that this is already a Java-String. The pure "Regex" is

```
\\left\.\s+\\beginarray\s+l\s+([\d\s\+=\-*\/%^x-z]+)\s+\\\s+([\d\s\+=\-*\/%^x-z]+)\s+\\\s+([\d\s\+=\-*\/%^x-z]+)\s+\\endarray\s+\\right\.
```

Also, this will match your string, and the contained (3) formulae, but if you change the number, it won't work anymore. Also a lot of other things might break this.
It looks a bit like your syntax is supposed to describe a tree:

```
left
  beginarray
    [formula]+
  endarray
right
```

Assuming this is only part of a greater syntax, and that there might be other stuff in between the elements (for example another array), you need more than regex. You'd need to define a grammar and analyze that.